Apps Scripts - .getLastColumn() works once in a for loop then errors out
I am trying to loop through Sheets and getLastColumn(). I activate the first sheet and get the last column, then I activate the next sheet, but this time I get an error on getLastColumn(). I am doing this in a for loop, could that be the issue?
    //sort fab, milling, turning, engraving
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Fab Schedule");
    sheet.activate;
  
    var lastColumnFab = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var lastColumn = lastColumnFab;
    var lastColumnMilling;
    var lastColumnTurning;
    var lastColumnEngraving;
    var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName(); 
    Logger.log(currentSheet);

    for(a=0;a<3;a++){ // 'a' is for looping through the different sheets
    Logger.log(a);

    // counting non-empty rows 
    var BValues = sheet.getRange("B3:B").getValues();
    var i=0;
    var singleBValue = "";
    //Logger.log(BValues[i]);
    for(i = 0; BValues[i] != ""; i++){
      singleBValue = BValues[i];
      //console.log({i,singleBValue});
    }
    var lastRow = i;
    i=i+3;

    // arrays begin with 0 // all rows and columns begin with 1
    sheet.getRange(3,2,lastRow,lastColumn).activate();
    //sheet.getRange('B3:V').activate(); //number of columns is different on every
    sheet
    var statusColumn = getHeaderNumber("Status")+1; //get header uses array, so it
    starts at 0
    var dueDateColumn = getHeaderNumber("Due Date")+1;
    var engineerColumn = getHeaderNumber("Engineer")+1;
  
    //sort by incomplete->complete, then
    sheet.getActiveRange().sort([{column: statusColumn, ascending: false}, {column: dueDateColumn, ascending: true},{column:engineerColumn, ascending: true}]);
  //sheet.getActiveRange().sort([{column: 14, ascending: false}]);//, {column: 18, ascending: true},{column:2, ascending: true}]);

  sheet.getRange(3,14,lastRow,lastColumn-14).setHorizontalAlignment("center"); //number of columns is different on every sheet
  sheet.getRange(3,1,lastRow,lastColumn).setVerticalAlignment("middle");
  sheet.getRange(3,1,lastRow,lastColumn).setFontFamily("Arial");
  sheet.getRange(3,1,lastRow,lastColumn).setFontSize(10);
  if (a==0){
      sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Milling Schedule");
      sheet.activate();
      var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName(); 
      Logger.log(currentSheet);
      lastColumnMilling = sheet.getLastColumn(); //error?
      lastColumn = lastColumnMilling;
    }

Exception: The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet. Sortbyincompleteanddate @ sort.gs:62

It seems your error message is the coordinates of a range.  Are you sure it is the lastColumnMilling statement.?  I believe it may be the sheet.getRange(3,14,lastRow,lastColumn-14) statement because lastColumn-14 is less than 1.

The lastColumn value is 22 or 23 or 24. So lastColumn-14 works fine. When I receive the error, the cursor is placed on the lastColumnMilling line,but to the right of sheet.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question and share a [mre] instead of showing just bits of code.

The code is not working correctly because the for (a loop iterates three times but the code only attempts to handle two sheets. Use a more structured approach, perhaps like this:
function test() {
  ['Fab Schedule', 'Milling Schedule', 'Turning Schedule', 'Engraving Schedule',]
    .forEach(sheetName => {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
      if (!sheet) {
        console.log(`There is no sheet by the name ${sheetName}`);
        return;
      }
      sortAndFormat_(sheet);
    });
}

function sortAndFormat_(sheet) {
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  sheet.getRange(3, 2, lastRow, lastColumn)
    .sort([
      { column: getHeaderNumber(sheet, 'Status') + 1, ascending: false },
      { column: getHeaderNumber(sheet, 'Due Date') + 1, ascending: true },
      { column: getHeaderNumber(sheet, 'Engineer') + 1, ascending: true },
    ]);
  sheet.getRange(3, 14, lastRow, lastColumn - 14).setHorizontalAlignment('center');
  sheet.getRange(3, 1, lastRow, lastColumn)
    .setVerticalAlignment('middle')
    .setFontFamily('Arial')
    .setFontSize(10);
}

Note that I've added a sheet parameter to the getHeaderNumber() call. You will need to adjust that function to accept and use the sheet parameter instead of locating the sheet with Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet() or similar means.
Use a more structured approach to clean up your code and make it easier to track and maintain. See Clean Code JavaScript and take a look at methods such as Array.forEach().

Thanks @doubleunary,  I did add the sheet parameter to the 'getHeaderNumber()' function, that really cleans up my code. I was incorrect about the number of iterations of my for loop, so that is straightened out.  I never new Array.forEach() was a thing, so I plan on using that to further clean up my code. As for my original problem of '.getLastColumn()', I still fail to understand why it worked in the beginning of my function, but now later on? Regardless, I used 'sheet.getRange(3,14,lastRow,sheet.getLastColumn()-14).setHorizontalAlignment("center");' and I can move on.

The problem in the original code is most likely because of the use of "active" status of a sheet to track where to get the last column. Use a more structured approach to clean up your code and make it easier to track and maintain. See Clean Code JavaScript.
